# How to add rewrite on existing Nginx config file

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have an existing Nginx config file that I've configured to work with a docker container that runs php. Below is the nginx config file:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
  }
```

Now I wanted to test a certain project in the nginx configuration, the project requires that I use its own configuration of nginx

```
    # nginx configuration

autoindex off;

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1;
  }
}
```

I am getting difficulties on adding the new configurations onto the already existing Nginx file that connects to the PHP container. I need some help on how I can add the new configurations without compromising the old Nginx file because the routes wont be redirected to the php container if I use the Nginx file that comes with the project.

Comment: why do you need to add a new config? if you have to add new config then there will be something new in the URL, something which is unique and using that unique keyword we can rewrite your Nginx config. Just need to identify the unique key in URL

Comment: @DupinderSingh the project came with an instruction to use the nginx file

Comment: Yes, I got it! but my question is  `location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1;
  }
}` what this will do ?

Comment: @DupinderSingh am not sure. when i tried the project on xxamp which uses apache it worked well but now i want to use nginx with docker but am getting issues with the routes. it always redirects to the index

Comment: What if you don't add `location / {   if (!-e $request_filename){     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1;   } }` in your ngnix what happens then ?

Comment: @DupinderSingh only the index.php page is loaded. when i go to other pages the route can be localhost/explore but the index.php page remains rendered

Comment: That is because you added this `location /` wait I will send you one repo link read it might help you

Comment: BTW if you describe more about your project structure and URL that you access that would be greate

Comment: https://github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv